# How to get IP Address for a cluster in Windows 2008 Server

Tags: vbscript, wmi, cluster-computing

I created a vbscript to obtain a bunch of system information from a server, and one thing I need to get is the IP Address of the server. Apparently I've only been getting the "heartbeat ip address", and that is not the one I need.

Is there a way with vbscript for me to tie in with wmi and get the ip address, private one I assume.

I tried this WMI class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371441(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is what I have

```
Option Explicit
'On Error Resume Next

Dim strIPAddress,objItem,colItems,objWMISrvc,strComputer,objAddr

strComputer = "."
Set objWMISrvc = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

getIPAddress

Sub getIPAddress()
  'Check if system is a cluster'
  strIPAddress = ""
  Set colItems = objWMISrvc.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSCluster_Network")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    For Each objItem in colItems
      'strIPAddress = "IP Address: " & objItem.
      For i = 0 to UBound(objItem.IPv4Addresses)
         strIPAddress = "IP Address (" & i & "): " & objItem.IPv4Addresses(i)
      Next
    Next
  End If
'############################################################
' These are all commented because this is how I WAS getting 
' the ip address but it only returned the heartbeat. 
' I will still be using this if I can somehow tell if a server is a cluster or not.
'If strIPAddress = "" Then
''  Dim i
  '' Set colItems = objWMISrvc.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
   'For Each objItem in colItems
    ''  If Not IsNull(objItem.IPAddress) Then
     ''    strIPAddress = objItem.IPAddress(0)
      ''   'For i = 0 to UBound(objItem.IPAddress)
       '' ' '   strIPAddress = strIPAddress & " | " & objItem.IPAddress(i)
        '' Next
     '' End If 
   'Next
'End If

WScript.Echo strIPAddress

End Sub
```

When my client ran this on their cluster server, it provided an empty msgbox, so it didn't pull an ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you need the `mscluster` namespace, not the `cimv2` namespace.

```
Set cluster = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/mscluster")
```

Second, what **is** the address you need? A cluster usually has several networks with separate IP address ranges. The [`MSCluster_Network`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class allows you to enumerate the networks and their network addresses:

```
For Each nw In cluster.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSCluster_Network")
  WScript.Echo nw.Name & vbTab & nw.Address
Next
```

The output should be something like this (note the `0` in the last octet, which is the network address, not an actual host address):

```
iSCSI   192.168.26.0
Live Migration  192.168.25.0
Management      192.168.23.0
Heartbeat       192.168.24.0
```

If you want the IP addresses of an individual cluster member, you can get them via the [`MSCluster_NetworkInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class:

```
hostname = "foobar"

For Each iface In cluster.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSCluster_NetworkInterface")
  If Left(iface.Name, Len(hostname)) = hostname Then
    WScript.Echo iface.Name & vbTab & iface.Address
  End If
Next
```

which should produce output like this:

```
foobar - iSCSI-0     192.168.26.17
foobar - Live Migration      192.168.25.23
foobar - Management  192.168.23.42
foobar - Heartbeat   192.168.24.13
```

Comment: Beautiful! Let me try this out and get back to you. It looks to be exactly what I need, and thank you for pointing out I was using the wrong namespace. I need to learn what is in each namespace so I can use the correct one in the future.

Comment: @Kiquenet C# should be able to query WMI too.